# Sinatra, Rails and Rack - User/Session Management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, rack, single-sign-on

Does anyone know of a way to authenticate in a Rails application and allow other Sinatra applications to pass that authentication token and session state through rack?

I'm looking for something that basically allows single sign on. (I already have the secret and key in the rails app with authentication, now looking to use that as the single sign on service with other Sinatra applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to use Rubycas client, which will allow me to use LDAP and push sessions to each ruby application I create.  Hancock is nice that it uses OpenID, but it is not what I need.

RubyCAS Client:
http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-client/

Comment: I ran into a couple more lately: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1 and http://oauth.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

I know its not exactly what your looking for but check out [hancock](http://github.com/atmos/hancock) on github.  Its a open source project for SSO in Sinatra.  If nothing else it will give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: Yeah I did evaluate it and it was interesting... I believe my solution will be CAS client and server

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is warden:

https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki

This is what devise uses.